# Routing in Web Api

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to set up a route on my web api project but I'm having a bit of trouble.

I'm trying to get the url to be as follows for my activate method in my AppsController:

```
/apps/{id}/activate/
```

I've tried the following in the WebApiConfig.cs

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ActivateAsset",
            routeTemplate: "{controller]/{id}/{type}/",
            default: new { controller = "Apps", type = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

which works, however, it messes up the rest of the routing; when I load the api it automatically performs a Get on my AppsController- which I do not want it to do!

Any ideas how I should map my routes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, sorted it...it was an issue with the ordering of the routes

I've updated my WebApiConfig.cs as follows:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "AppsActivation",
            routeTemplate: "{controller}/{id}/{type}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Apps", type = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Comment: Additionally, you can use the `{action}` parameter. This will allow you to specifically call a function from your API. The action name can be designated in the API's code-behind using `<ActionName("myActionName")>` (in VB.net). This way your API won't confuse your routes again...unless you misname a parameter somewhere or forget to make your API function public...which I've done way too many times.

Answer (score 0):

> Web API 2 supports a new type of routing, called attribute routing. As
>   the name implies, attribute routing uses attributes to define routes.
>   Attribute routing gives you more control over the URIs in your web
>   API.

```
[Route("apps/{id}/activate")]
public App Index(int id) { ... }
```

More about [`Attribute Routing`](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)